# Is it possible to take any OS iso and use it to install to a hard drive WHILE staying on windows?

Tags: installation, mount, iso-image, emulation

Say i have some hard drives, and each of them needs to install its own OS to it, and i have a windows machine, and i can also hot swap these hard drives, is it possible to take for example a Ubuntu ISO, mount it THEN install the OS to the hard drive without making a bootable usb, restart windows, boot to usb, then use it to install to this hard drive?

the idea is take any installer ISO and sort of emulate so i can run it like I'm running it as a bootable drive but instead inside windows (or any other OS) then use it to install the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the ISO inside a virtual machine software (such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)), connecting the hard drives to the VM, and following the installing procedure as usual.

---

## How to install a OS in a raw disk, using VirtualBox

1. Connect your hard drive to the computer.
2. Open Windows **Disk Management** *(<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> > Disk Management)*
3. Identify your disk's number. For example, in the case of the picture below, the disk number we're interested in is #0 (imagine that it didn't have `C:` in it). You can see the disk number at the left-hand side, in the list at the bottom.

   [image: Disk Management]
4. Open a command line **with administrator privileges** and run `diskpart`:

   Select the disk we're interested in (the number should be the one identified before):

   ```
   DISKPART> select disk 0
   ```

   *Disconnect* the disk:

   ```
   DISKPART> offline disk
   ```

   Make the disk writable:

   ```
   DISKPART> attributes disk clear readonly
   ```

   Quit `diskpart`:
       DISKPART> exit
5. Create a VMDK file for your hard drive with the command line **with administrator privileges**:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename C:\PATH\WHERE\SAVE\theImage.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive0
   ```

   Note that you have to replace the number in `\PhysicalDrive0` with the disk number found in step 3.
6. Open VirtualBox and create a new virtual machine, with the disk file we just created. If you have any problem *(VERR_ACCESS_DENIED)*, try opening VirtualBox with admin privileges.

   [image: Creating a new VM with the created file]
7. Once created, enter the machine's settings (without starting it, yet), and go to *Storage*. There, add the ISO of the OS you want to install:

   [image: Adding a ISO to the VM]
8. Start the virtual machine, and proceed to install your OS as usual. The disk and partitions that'll appear in the installation program will be from the hard drive we used through all this process.

   [image: Partition table in Ubuntu installation]

And that's it!

Comment: yeah i thought about using a virtual machine and use it to install the OSes, thing is, how can i mount the hard drive into the virtual machine without assigning a drive letter to winodws or something, plus i just tried it, and when i click on devices and try to attach a harddrive, i don't see it, and i don't know if it's possible because the only way i can think of that in order to make the hard drive recognize by windows is to format it as ntfs, and assign letter to it, i dont want that, i want raw hard drive and format it to whatever i want, even apple's own extended journal filetype

Comment: With VirtualBox I've been able to successfully attach hard drives that weren't recognized by Windows (e.g.: an ext4-formatted drive). Which VM software are you using?

Comment: Currently I'm using VirtualBox, because VMware required me to specify hard drive storage which i don't want, so lets start from scratch, i have windows, and a hard drive plugged in, the hard drive is completely empty without partitions, now what? which settings should i choose when creating virtual machine? should i choose the DOS option or anything won't matter? and how can i mount this hard drive after i booted up the virtual machine? i don't see it in the devices tap

Comment: I assume your hard drives are directly connected to the PC using SATA, not USB, right?

Comment: yes, I'm using a laptop with optical hard drive adapter (the thing you replace the optical drive with to use normal sata hard drives)

Comment: @OrsanAwwad https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk

Comment: Hewbot, I can't thank you enough for writing that tutorial, it worked well and i managed to install ubuntu, however if i try to boot directly to the ubuntu from bios the hdd doesn't show up, what did i miss?

Comment: Never mind that, i had to choose boot from cd/dvd (because I'm using the optical drive adapter i believe) which is little strange, any way, THANK YOU, again, you are one amazing person.

Comment: Every time I try to create a new vmdk I get an error stating `Cannot open the raw disk '\.\PhysicalDrive0': VERR_SHARING_VIOLATION`. Any suggestions?