# install linux on a separate drive from within windows without rebooting

Tags: windows-7, linux, installation, linux-mint

Is it possible to install Linux on a separate drive without rebooting to the live DVD?  My setup is I have a 500GB internal HDD with windows and a bland 480GB internal SSD on which I would like to install Mint.  I'd prefer to install Mint to the SSD while continuing to work in Windows rather than having to reboot to the live DVD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to take any OS iso and use it to install to a hard drive WHILE staying on windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/1066290/is-it-possible-to-take-any-os-iso-and-use-it-to-install-to-a-hard-drive-while-st)

Comment: @Moab That link details how to install linux on a partition while running linux.  I am running windows.

Comment: @Hewbot That link details how to do it on Windows 10.  The process may not be different, but I immediately hit failures creating the VMDK because VBoxManage thinks the drive is still connected.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use Virtual Box to install it.
I boot the VM from an iso file, then connect the drive (mine is usb) to the guest OS via VirtualBox's Devices menu and proceed to install.

If you need to boot from a usb disk you can do that as well, although it is more complicated.