# Can't create vmdk from raw disk: VERR_SHARING_VIOLATION

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, virtualbox

I'm using [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1066290/is-it-possible-to-take-any-os-iso-and-use-it-to-install-to-a-hard-drive-while-st?answertab=votes#tab-top) to create a vmdk file from my secondary hard drive.  My problem is I keep getting an error stating:

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Cannot open the raw disk '\\.\PhysicalDrive0': VERR_SHARING_VIOLATION
VBoxManage.exe: error: The raw disk vmdk file was not created
```

I have followed the steps to disconnect the drive using DISKPART, but I still get the same error.

What is happening?

Answer (score -2):

I read a "solution" - to plug out and back plug in the SATA cabel (really when Win is started), then drive is not shared anymore and rawdisc access works (I am not sure if it will work after Win reboot)...

Comment: This would only work if the SATA controller supported this functionality.  This should not be tested unless, you know without a shadow of a doubt, your SATA controller and your drives support being hot swapped.

Comment: I have re-inserted my USB drive (safely ejecting each time) to solve this issue I believe (I boot a guest VM from it).  Something about leaving it plugged in for a while, over restarts/sleeps, or some program getting a lock on it may have been the problem.

Comment: By the way, if you wanted to simulate this behavior, I have had several external disks where the connection and lock on the drive is held worse than others.  This must be indicative of certain characteristics of the drive by itself, or how it sets itself up in Windows, assuming the drivers are all the same basic microsoft storage drives.  LockHunter reports a single System process that may be running a backup, or some other sort of disk management routine, where you can see SIDs in the file path.  I open Disk Management and remove the drive letter, which seems to break these locks.